# How to use select in c#(mysql)

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a database and i need to sort items in it. I created an array that has string variables that i need to compare and display rows that has that text.
But my database keep updating for every array member. 
for example: if i have `string array = {"123,"321,"456"}` then my database display only one row, that contains one of these members. But i need to display all 3 of them. How do i do it correct? Maybe there is some way to pass string array into `Contains` method?

```
bool[] check = new bool[]{spain_check.Checked, france_check.Checked, england_check.Checked, germany_check.Checked, brazil_check.Checked,
                            argentina_check.Checked, belgium_check.Checked, italy_check.Checked, netherland_check.Checked, portugal_check.Checked};
string[] str = new string[]{spain_check.Text, france_check.Text, england_check.Text, germany_check.Text, brazil_check.Text,
                            argentina_check.Text, belgium_check.Text, italy_check.Text, netherland_check.Text, portugal_check.Text};
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    if (check[i] == false)
    {
        str[i] = "";
    }
}
string msg = "";
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    if (str[i] == "")
        continue;
        msg += str[i] + '\n';
        var query = from o in this.leodata.main
                    where o.country.Contains(str[i])
                    select o;
        mainBindingSource.DataSource = query.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove your `for` loop and change your query to below:

```
var query = from o in this.leodata.main
where str.Any(obj=> o.country.Contains(obj))
select o;
```

Comment: i did like you said, but now it doesnt update at all, it just displays the whole table

Comment: Are you sure you haven't added all countries in the database to the str[] array?

Comment: yep, i had all countrie in it. is there any method do delete string member?

Comment: I think I haven't got what you are trying to achieve to? I made a simple demo which you can see here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NjIZXK